# Find the maximum likelihood of $f(x|β) = \frac{1}{β}\,e^{-x/β}$

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Let X1, · · · , Xn be an i.i.d. sample from an exponential distribution with the density function. Find the maximum likelihood of 
$$f(x|β) = \frac{1}{β}\,e^{-x/β}$$

First, I need to find: 
$$p(x|β) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{β} \,e^{-x_i/β}$$ but I'm not sure how I can simplify the equation above.

Here's my attempt:
$$p(x|β) = \frac{1}{β^n} \,e^\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{β}$$

Then, I have to find the negative log-likelihood:
$$L(x|β) = \ nlog(β) + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{β}$$

Then, I have to differentiate with respect to β to get the MLE. So
$$β = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}$$

Is this correct? I'm unsure about my simplification.

Comment: Likelihood based on the sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is $L(\beta\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i\mid \beta)$, a function of $\beta$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101481/calculating-maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-the-exponential-distribution-and-pr.

Comment: When you start simplifying the expression, be careful with the product of the exponentials. It should be $$=\frac{1}{\prod_i \beta_i}e^{\sum_i \frac{-x}{\beta_i}}$$

Comment: It looks fine, notice that the maximum likelihood estimator coincided with the sample mean. Anyway notice that the likelihood function is a function of $\beta$ where the sample $\pmb{X}$ is given as @StubbornAtom mentioned above.